# displaying the selected image using tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I want to know whether I can display an image from the path I have selected? like, I have a path for example: c:\user\desktop\33.jpg, and I want to take only that jpg file and I have to display that image using label or something. If it is possible, I want to know how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you could add a bit of code to the question about what you have tried so far in this regard,that would be a big help

Comment: @shaktimaan i have not tried anything, i want to know, even if you take your own example is also fine for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a sample code for what you are asking:

```
from Tkinter import Label,Tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkFileDialog
root = Tk()

path=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Image File",'.jpg')])
im = Image.open(path)
tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
myvar=Label(root,image = tkimage)
myvar.image = tkimage
myvar.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You will be wanting to add a button for calling the `askopenfilename` because right now its calling it the moment the program begins.
Also you might wanna add more file extensions to `filetypes`